# Angular Karma Test Error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined

Tags: angular, jasmine, automated-tests, karma-jasmine

I recvied some code that I have to write some unint/e2e tests for. My only problem is anytime I run an ng test, I receive this error:

```
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined\nat http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.bundle.js:1:1\n\nReferenceError: System is not defined\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.bundle.js:1:1",
    "str": "Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined\nat http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.bundle.js:1:1\n\nReferenceError: System is not defined\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.bundle.js:1:1"
  }

Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined\nat http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.bundle.js:1:1\n\nReferenceError: System is not defined\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.bundle.js:1:1",
    "str": "Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined\nat http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.bundle.js:1:1\n\nReferenceError: System is not defined\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.bundle.js:1:1"
  }
```

I have a feeling it is somthing with the angular.json file as well as the tsconf.spec file. I have tried many possible solutions I found online but always recive the same error. Here is my tsconf.spec and angular.josn. Thank you.

configspec:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Angular.json

```
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": ""
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
         "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": []


    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

I am currently using angular 6, I have gone back to 4 but still receive the same error.

Edit: Solved this problem but it was a strange solution. In my angular.json file there was a script that was causing this error. I simply deleted the script and all is well.

Comment: The problem is that system.js is not able to be found. You need to make sure that system.js is wired up in your spec config. Not exactly sure how to do that, though.

Comment: Thank you. I ran npm i systemjs and was able to run karma. But I am unsure if everything is working properly as I haven't had time to write a test. Will update when I do.